# How to replace multiple address abbreviations in an address string using XSLT 2.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

Given: XSLT 2.0; Saxon EE 9.6.0.4

Source XML:

```
<clients>
    <client id="1">
        <address>12345 Elm Dr</address>
    </client>
    <client id="2">
        <address>12345 Elm Cr</address>
    </client>
</clients>
```

I need to do some comparisons of addresses to find matches where one address may use an abbreviation and the address I'm comparing to may not.  Here are a few examples of what I mean:

```
Ave = Avenue
Blvd = Boulevard
Cir = Circle
Ct = Court
Dr = Drive
Hwy = Highway
```

The address searched on is passed to the stylesheet as a param, so say this address was passed in to the following sample stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:param name="searchAddr">12345 Elm Drive</xsl:param>
    <xsl:variable name="punctuation">
        <xsl:text> .!@#$%^*()_+{}[]|`\:;?,*-=/</xsl:text>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="clients/client[address[upper-case(translate(.,$punctuation,'')) = upper-case(translate($searchAddr,$punctuation,''))]]">
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

NOTE: 
--I'm already using translate() to remove all the punctuation and upper-case() to control case in the comparison.

--I don't need to permanently replace the strings in the output, I only need to replace them for the comparison.

--We realize this isn't a 100% reliable method of address matching but in this case we don't need it to be...just want to get the low hanging fruit.

I'm thinking there is a better way to do this than 20 nested replace functions or calling a template to loop through each abbreviation.  Ideas?

Comment: Can an address contain more than one abbreviation?

Comment: @michael.hor257k - I guess it could be 12345 Cir Dr for Circle Drive or similar.  We don't have to catch every single nuance in this case but I definately appreciate where you are going.

Comment: If the answer is yes, then I don't see how you can avoid chaining multiple replace operations *in series*. Martin Honnen's very clever solution works *in parallel*, and thus will not suit your needs.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Thank you for your insight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if there's a more elegant way than nesting/chaining 20 replace operations. I don't think there is, only different ways to express that operation.

So how about getting on with life:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:param name="searchAddr">12345 Elm Drive</xsl:param>

    <xsl:key name="sanitized-adresses" match="client" use="
        replace(
        replace(
        replace(
        replace(
        replace(
        replace(
        replace(
            upper-case(normalize-space(address))
        ,'\p{P}', '')
        ,'(^|\W)AVE($|\W)', '$1AVENUE$2')
        ,'(^|\W)DR($|\W)', '$1DRIVE$2')
        ,'(^|\W)BLVD($|\W)', '$1BOULEVARD$2')
        ,'(^|\W)CI?R($|\W)', '$1CIRCLE$2')
        ,'(^|\W)CT($|\W)', '$1COURT$2')
        ,'(^|\W)HWY($|\W)', '$1HIGHWAY$2')
    " />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:copy-of select="key('sanitized-adresses', upper-case($searchAddr))" />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Notes:

- The `\p{P}` is the Unicode character class that matches all punctuation.
- XSLT 2.0 regular expressions don't have word boundaries, therefore `(^|\W)` and `($|\W)` are substitutes for `\b`.
- It also does not have look-behinds or look-aheads, therefore we need `$1` and `$2` in the replacement string.
- I included `normalize-space()` to avoid whitespace issues
- The `<xsl:key>` is not strictly necessary, I added it to make the main template more pleasant to look at.

If you want, create an `<xsl:function>` that does the address sanitation, this way you can re-use it to sanitize the parameter, making overall usage more convenient.

Comment: Thank you.  Interesting on the \p{P}

Comment: I decided that multiple abbreviations in the same address were important considerations so I opted for your solution.  I also used the xsl:function you recommended.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could consider to define a mapping from abbreviations to strings, for instance as a parameter

```
<xsl:param name="mapping">
    <map from="Ave" to="Avenue"/>
    <map from="Blvd" to="Boulevard"/>
    <map from="Dr" to="Drive"/>
</xsl:param>
```

and then you could select

```
    <xsl:copy-of select="clients/client[matches(address, concat('^', $searchAddr, '$')) or (some $map in $mapping/map satisfies matches(replace(address, $map/@from, $map/@to), concat('^', $searchAddr, '$')))]"/>
```

Comment: Martin Honnen - Thank you, it works.  I'm not sure I totally understand it yet though.  So it either matches it exactly OR it is contained in the map.  Could you explain 'some $map' in more detail?  Also what problem concatenating '^' and '$' solves?

Comment: @johkar - The second argument of `matches()` is a regex. Concatenating `^` and `$` anchors the regex to beginning and end. So you end up with `^12345 Elm Drive$`

Comment: @johkar, instead of your approach of "calling a template to loop through each abbreviation" I suggested to make use of the XPath 2.0 and later https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#id-quantified-expressions `some $var in $sequence satisfies condition-expression`. In this case we check with `some $map in $mapping/map` that there is at least one `map` element in the parameter `$mapping` where the `address  with the replacement of the abbreviation `@to` by `@from` matches the `$searchAddr` parameter. The anchors `^` and `$` were already explained by Daniel, to have an exact match from the start and end.

Comment: @MartinHonnen  Very informative.  I'll can use this concept for other needs too.  Thanks.